# Website using .less renders fine in Safari/FF/And any other modern browser but not in IE

Tags: css, less, modernizr

I'm currently launching a website using .lesscss. Everything works fine in most modern browsers but it just doesn't want to work in IE 6/7/8/9.

You can find the website on: http://diejongens.com/home

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: It's hard to tell as I don't know what the site is supposed to look like. Your font styling looks fine in ie 7, the colours & sizes don't seem to have any problems. Is it the layout that's causing you issues?

Comment: Yeah it is, everything should be centered and not left aligned. The weird thing is that it is taking the font styling and everything but not the overall layout.

Answer (score -1):

For one ../css/responsive.less should be /css/responsive.less . '../' can't work if you are already in the root.

But the real problem is that you shouldn't use .less, but .css. so use [/css/responsive.css](http://diejongens.com/css/responsive.css) . Less rewrites the css, but if you link directly to the .less file the pre-processor doesn't do it's job, and browsers will not know what to do with the nonstandard less syntax.

*Groetjes uit Holland.*

Comment: He is using `less.js`; it takes `.less` files, not `.css` files, and there is no preprocessing.